# Study convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{e^x + 1}$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Study convergence of $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{e^x + 1}$$

First of all, I can only use the comparison test or the limit comparison test, but I don't know to witch series compare it.

Is known that polynomials of grade $n \gt e^{x}$ and that $\sqrt{x} \lt x$ and so $e^{\sqrt{x}} \lt e^{x}$. Any hints how to proceed ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $0\le e^{\sqrt{x}}\le e^{x/2}$ for $x\ge4$, $0\le\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{e^x+1}<\frac12e^4$ for $x\in[0,\,4)$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Why would I want to find an upper bound for $x \in [0,4)$ if I need to find if the integral converges when x tends to infinity.

Comment: I think i got it. Since the $\int_{4}^{\infty} f(x) = arctan(e^{\sqrt(x)}) = \frac{\pi}{2} - L$. What is not natural to me though, is to know to what compare it so easily. It took me some time to realise that.

Comment: @Karl Just in case the $\int_0^4$ part diverges. So we check the contributions either side of $4$. I knew a comparison to a more slowly-growing exponential function would help, so it boiled down to comparing $\sqrt{x}$ to $x/2$ (say).

Answer (score 0):

The function $\displaystyle f(x) := \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{1+e^x}$ is clearly continous in the interval $[0,\infty)$.

As $x$ approaches $0$ it's perfectly integrable and as $x$ approaches $+\infty$ it decays as a negative exponential. So its integral is finite.